# Single line with numeric number and alpha characters, regex is not recognizing numeric number

Tags: regex

What I am doing is writing a regular expression that keys on eight numeric values on a single line.  By itself, the numeric numbers are being recognized.  When I place the numbers in a line with alpha characters, the numeric values are not be picked up.

**This is the test data:**  Line 3 and 4 are recognized with no problem.  The expression should also pickup line 1 and 2.

1. This is my account number 32145678
2. t 12345678
3. 43215678
4. 54321678

This is my regex:

```
(?is)^(?![A-Za-z])(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: I think #KnutForkalsrud just forgot the 0 in the series[0-9], but I understood.  WRT "t 12345678" it was an example to prove the pattern should skip the alpha character and match on the 8 consecutive numbers following it.

Comment: updated.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about
`^.*(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$`?
It doesn't bother matching anything other than the number at the end of the line.